# What is a good word for the object under review?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a good general term for "the thing that is being reviewed"?

- The activity is *reviewing*
- The product is a *review*
- The person conducting doing it is the *reviewer*
- The object being reviewed is *?*

The closest I've come up with is *specimen*, but that is more the subject of scientific scrutiny.  I could use a more general term like *subject* but I would have to prefix it to make the context clear (e.g. *review subject*).

Answer (score 5):

As I read the question, really the subject line, the noun *subject* came immediately to mind.  If you need to clarify, and I am not sure you would, *the subject of our review*, or words to that effect, ought to do it.

Answer (score 1):

*Reviewee*?
Try 'interview':

> The activity is *interviewing*
>   The product is an *interview*
>   The person conducting doing it is the *interviewer*
>   The object being interviewed is the *interviewee*

Using the stem of the word, it is likely that the appropriate word would be **reviewee**, although it seems to refer specifically to people undergoing a review rather than absolutely any subject; if you're going for consistency between words, 'reviewee' seems to be the obvious choice (even if Chrome's spellcheck flags it as a non-word).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context I would go with one of the following:

- **matter**
- **target**
- **object**

Answer (score 0):

The object under review is the **review subject**. The thing or the **subject-matter** the review is about.

Comment: Just noticed my answer is congruent with @Michael Owen Sartins answer.