# Is "object of discussion" an established term, or is there another word for that?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns, word-usage

In a review of, let's say, predatory habits of some animals, the *subject* of the discussion is the predatory habits.

Is it correct to say that the animals, then, are the *objects of discussion* or *objects under review*? Or is there a different term that would communicate this?

I found [a related post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161750/what-is-a-good-word-for-the-object-under-review) or perhaps I am asking a duplicate but I did not find a satisfactory answer there either.

Comment: I would say it's *not* correct to invoke the grammatical subject/object categories in this context. In general, the ***subject** of discussion/debate* is the *thing actually being discussed*, whereas the [***object** of the debate*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22object+of+the+debate%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is the *objective, purpose, aim*.  That's to say it's the ***reason*** for having the discussion in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a review of, let's say, predatory habits of some animals, the *subject* of the discussion is the predatory habits.

No, the "subject" is "predatory habits of some animals".

> subject — topic: something that is being discussed, examined, or otherwise dealt with

There isn't a significant distinction between "subject of discussion" and "objects of discussion". And if you can say a review is *of* something than it is correct to say that something is the *subject* of the review (or discussion).

> Is it correct to say that the animals, then, are the *objects of discussion* or *objects under review*? Or is there a different term that would communicate this?

You can refer to the specific objects you care about: "The animals involved in the studies..."

But any term that could do what you request would have an inherent ambiguity. There is no significant distinction between "predatory habits" and "animals" that would allow a term to single out "animals" as the "objects of review" -- linguistically, they are both objects. The only way to do something like this is to use additional context to inform your reader which of the various objects you are referring to.

Comment: PS) My post is fairly likely to be controversial so take it with a grain of salt. Someone out there is likely to draw some semantic distinction between the various objects but, pragmatically, such distinctions are likely to confuse readers.

Answer (score 0):

you can call it the topic or subject.

topic- A matter dealt with in a text, discourse, or conversation

subject - A person or thing that is being discussed, described, or dealt with

www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/topic

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/subject?q=subject

Comment: So, in the case of the example that I mentioned, would it be incorrect to say that the subject of discussion is *predatory habits* rather than the *animals*

Comment: :-) it will be totally correct

Comment: Please attribute your work.

Comment: @vickyace I am confused here. The subject of discussion is *predatory habits*, which will be focused on in detail. But I am considering the case of, lets say, hyenas and tigers, what term will denote these animals.

Comment: @MattЭллен My work is more complex (in terms of scientific content); I would rather not discuss it here.

Comment: @WYSIWYG I was refering to vikyace's use of other's work in his answer.

Comment: these are something which would be used to exemplify the subject (present it self as an example) or used as an example to explain the subject.